# Selenium click anchor link with class attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help how to click the below link using selenium

```
<a class=”btn btn-primary btn-large” href="target-URL">Submit</a>
```

I tried using below options

1. linkText
2. partialLinkText
3. CssSelector
4. contains - logic which checks the URL text

Comment: tony, is the given answers worked for u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='target-URL']").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains@class,'btn '] and contains(@class, 'btn-large') and contains(text(), 'Submit')")).click()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But i changed the parenthesis      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'btn ') and contains(@class, 'btn-large') and contains(text(), 'Submit')]")).click();

Answer (score 1):

Give full xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/a").click();
```

Can try with tag name

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("a").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this is just:

```
driver.findElment(By.linkText("Submit")).click();
```

But, I'm pretty sure you've already tried that. Check if the element is in `iframe`/`frame`. If yes, you need to switch to it and only then find the link element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_name_or_id");
```

To switch back in the main context, use `defaultContent()`:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: I tried that it didn't work for me. I am using firefox webdriver